# How to do transfer learning for yolo object detection algorithm?

Tags: neural-network, training-data, yolo

I have successfully trained yolo for predicting my own images  with [this article](https://timebutt.github.io/static/how-to-train-yolov2-to-detect-custom-objects/). In there I  changed classes = 5 (I trained for 5 classes) and filters to 50 in line 224 in my cfg file.
What I want is I want to do transfer learning for yolo with training the last fully connected layer and the softmax layer.
My cfg file is as follows.

```
[net]
batch=64
subdivisions=8
height=416
width=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.0001
max_batches = 45000
policy=steps
steps=100,25000,35000
scales=10,.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky


#######

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[route]
layers=-9

[reorg]
stride=2

[route]
layers=-1,-3

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=50
activation=linear

[region]
anchors = 1.08,1.19,  3.42,4.41,  6.63,11.38,  9.42,5.11,  16.62,10.52
bias_match=1
classes=5
coords=4
num=5
softmax=1
jitter=.2
rescore=1

object_scale=5
noobject_scale=1
class_scale=1
coord_scale=1

absolute=1
thresh = .6
random=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is `filters=(classes + 5)*5`

Reference: [Here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects)

Answer (score 1):

With 5 classes, you need to set filters to 30 not 50.
filters = (number of classes+1 )* 5

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using the pjreddie/darknet framework for the YOLO implementation.
If that's the case, then you set an additional parameter `stopbackward=1` at the layer above which you don't need the update.
In `parse.c` file, at line 724:

```
l.stopbackward = option_find_int_quiet(options, "stopbackward", 0);
```

So this means its a parameter at every layer, just like `batch_normalize=1` you can specify `stopbackward=1`. So any layers above this will not be updated. This is also seen in file `network.c` at Line 272:

```
if(l.stopbackward) break;
```